# pyqt5-tools: designer.exe missing

Tags: python-3.x, pycharm, pyqt5

I installed `pyqt5-tools` with PyCharm but when I open the related folder inside `site-packages` of my virtual environment, I notice that `designer.exe` is missing. This happens even if I install it in the system interpreter using `pip install pyqt5-tools`. Is this a bug that I should report or am I missing something?

I am using Windows 10, Python 3.8.5 and PyCharm Professional 2020.3.3.

Here some screeshot. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Have you checked `site-packages\qt5_applications\`?

According to https://pypi.org/project/pyqt5-tools/:

> As of pyqt5-tools v2 the package has been broken down into three pieces. The wrappers remain here but the plugins are located in pyqt5-plugins and the applications are in qt5-applications.